# サイトを公開する時、どこで発表するべき？

Tags: 討議

おかげさまで、日本語が徐々に完成に近づいてきています。

サイトの公開日はまだ未定ですが、11月中になりそうです。

もちろん皆さまの口コミも期待していますが、それ以外の発表も考えるべきと思っています。

例えば、英語のStack Exchangeブログの日本語での記事で発表もできますし、Joel Spolsky（Stack ExchangeのCEO）がツィッターで発表することも可能です。

Stack Exchange以外に、日本語のブログ等、アイデアがあれば、ご教示ください！

Answer (score 4):

技術系のコミュニティでは[「はてな」](http://www.hatena.ne.jp)が昔から人気があるので、[「はてなニュース」](http://hatenanews.com/articles/about)にニュースリリースの送付をするのというのはどうでしょうか？
以下URLの「ニュースリリースの送付について」にニュースリリースの送付方法が書かれています。
http://hatenanews.com/articles/about

Answer (score 4):

**QiitaにSOの実用的な紹介記事を投稿する**

たとえば信用度・バッジ・権限の仕組みについてなど。

Qiitaには「教えたがり」「知りたがり」なプログラマが集まっていると思います。

ただ、まずQiitaさんと共存繁栄の道を話し合った方がよいかも。個人的にQiitaがSOの競合になるのではと思っています。
というのも、Qiitaの目指す、「プログラミングに関する知識を記録、共有する最適なサービス」がSOのミッションとかぶるところがあるので。

Comment: SOの使い方や文化について、Qiitaで紹介するのはとても良いと思います。ただ、一点気になることがあったのでコメントさせてください。  

当初のQiitaはQ&Aサイトでしたので、確かにSOと真っ向から競合するサービスだったと思います。（現在でもteratailあたりはそうですね）  

ですが、現在のQiitaはユーザーが知見を書き残していく場所としての色合いが強くなっており、どちらかというと技術ブログの一種として扱われているように思います。  

本家SOでも「その答えは○○だよ。詳しくは僕のブログに記事を書いておいたから読んでね」という回答はよく見かけます。これが日本では「その答えは○○だよ。詳しくはQiitaに記事を書いておいたから読んでね」になるのでしょう。  

逆に、Qiitaを探しても見つからなかった情報は、SOで質問すればよいのでしょう。  
個人的には、これは競合する要素がほとんどない、理想的な共存に思えます。ミッションが被っていることはむしろプラスに働くのではと期待すらしてしまいます。  

いろいろ書きましたが、結論としてはentoさんと同じです。日本語版SOを繁栄させていく上で、Qiitaはこの上なく良いパートナーになってくれることでしょう。（というより、ユーザーが勝手にそういう使い方をします。）

Answer (score 3):

StackExchange 英語サイトに日本からアクセスした場合に案内するのが効果的だと思います。

画像は Amazon.com から Amazon.co.jp への誘導バナーです。同じようなことができれば。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: アイデアありがとうございます！ポルトガル語の場合にメインサイトの右側にポルトガル語の報告をしましたが、これもグッドアイデアですね！開発者と話してみます。

Answer (score 2):

IT系の話題に強いニュースメディアに紹介記事を書いてもらうのがいいと思います。TechCrunch Japan http://jp.techcrunch.com/ とか、ITmedia http://www.itmedia.co.jp/ とか。わざわざ頼まなくても彼らは勝手に記事を書くと思いますが。

Joel さんのツイートはとても効果が高そうですね。海外情報をウォッチしている先進的な日本のプログラマたちがすぐにキャッチして、そこからバイラルでどんどん広がると思いますし、IT系メディアが記事を書く際の「一次情報ソース」としても利用され得るので、一石二鳥だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

### 参考資料

#### ユーザー規模

- 日本全体の「IT人材」は約120万人 — [2013年5月のIPAの報告書](https://jinzaiipedia.ipa.go.jp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/researchreport_docs_20130515_002.pdf)より
- はてなに登録している「エンジニア<sup>*1</sup>」は約130万人 — [2014年10-12月版はてなメディアガイド](http://hatenacorp.jp/ads)より、「登録ユーザー400万人、うち33%<sup>*2</sup>がエンジニア」
- 日本からstackoverflow.comへの月間アクセスユーザーは約38万人 — [quantcastによる訪問者解析](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=JP)より

<sub>*1 「エンジニア=プログラマ」かは不明</sub>
<sub>*2 母数が登録ユーザー全体かは明記されていないが、自社調べによる数字なので、おそらく登録ユーザーが母数</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**日本で展開しているソフトウェア技術提供元に直接連絡する**

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/support/)は公式に「StackOverflowで中の人が質問に答えます」とサポートページにリンクを掲載しています。他にもオープンソースソフトウェアで「質問はこのタグでSOへどうぞ」などとしているのをみかけます。

例えば

- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/support/)
- [fluentd](http://docs.fluentd.org/ja/articles/quickstart)
- [OpenPNE](http://www.openpne.jp/)
- [enchant.js](http://enchantjs.com/ja/)

などに

- サポートページに日本語版SOへのリンクを加える
- 日本語版SOにアクティブに参加する
- → よりよい技術サポートにつながります

と提案するのはどうでしょうか。

タイミングとしてはある程度コミュニティの運営が回るようになってからがよいかもしれません。

追記: モデレーションが追いつかなくなることを心配して上のように書きましたが、少しずつ「提携」するならば、質問者と回答者の両方に参加してもらえるので公開初期からやってちょうどよいかもしれません。

参考: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Answer (score 1):

- [スラッシュドット・ジャパン](http://slashdot.jp/)にたれこむ。
- [reddit日本語版](http://www.reddit.com/r/ja)にポストする。

Answer (score 1):

オープンソースソフトウェアを GitHub で公開することは日本でも一般的になっています。
GitHub の README に貼ることができるバッジを用意するのはどうでしょう。
次のようなイメージです。

- バッジには該当ソフトウェアについての Q&A 件数が標示される
- バッジをクリックすると、該当ソフトウェアのQ&A検索結果が表示される

参考までに、次の画像は [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) と [Waffle.io](https://waffle.io) のバッジを README に貼り付けたところです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

アーリーアダプターに拾って貰うならば TechCrunch だと思います。
ただしアーリーアダプターは人に質問するよりも自力でなんとかしてしまうので、まずはこのサイトが情報のデータベースにならなければなりません。
多くの質問と回答をストックして、このサイトでないと見れない情報サイトに仕上げる必要があります。

ちなみに Qiita という声もあがっていますが、jmac さんはご存じか分かりませんが Stack Overflow と Qiita は同じ系列のサイトであって言ってみればライバルの様な存在です。
日本では現状 Qiita の方が人気があると思いますです。

Answer (score 1):

**雑誌で取り上げてもらう**
Web Designingの担当者に話をしたところ1/2ページ割いても良いよ、という返事をもらいました。原稿は月末締め切りで、毎月19日発売なので告知したいタイミングがあったらご連絡くださいとのことでした。

Answer (score 1):

ある程度質問が増えるまでは質問があったことを通知するTwitter　Botを運用してもいいかもしれません。

Comment: 英語版でも、TwitterもFacebookも手動で管理しています。自動化するメリットはありますか？