# Stack Overflow日本語版広告アイデア募集

Tags: 討議, 広告

公開と同時に広告が必要でしたので、取り急ぎマーケティングの方で2つを作成しました：

> [image: タイプA]
>
> [image: タイプB]

取り急ぎでしたので、追加したり、新しいコピー、色やデザイン等も更新可能です。

---

Stack Overflowポルトガル語版をオープンした時、英語版のメインサイトで広告を出しました。

広告内容は

- 「Hello World、Stack Overflowポルトガル語版の公式オープン」
- 「java html .net php ポルトガル語 regex mysql」（言語としてStack Overflowにポルトガル語を追加した感じ）
- 「スタック・オーバーフローが発生しましたか？ポルトガル語版で解決」
- 「あなたの言語も話す」
- 「C#は複雑。英語も」

等を作成しました。

もちろん、「[サイトを公開する時、どこで発表するべき？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/230/%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e5%85%ac%e9%96%8b%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%99%82-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%93%e3%81%a7%e7%99%ba%e8%a1%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8d)」も参考になりますが、ポルトガル語版と同じような広告アイデアがあれば、ぜひご教示ください。

広告のサイズ：

- Stack Overflowの質問ページ（ログインせず質問ページの一番上）： 728px x 90px
- Stack Overflowのメインページ（ログインせずメインページの右側）： 220px x 250px

[image: その1]
[image: その2]

Comment: 質問内容を把握しやすいよう、画像と文章の順番を入れかえました。

Answer (score 10):

**日本語でok**

[image]

[日本語でおk](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8Ak)というネットスラングをややニュートラルな表記にしたものです。

---

魔がさして、[広告用画像にテキストをのっけられるherokuアプリ](https://adsopop.herokuapp.com/)を作りました。上の画像はこれで生成したものです

Answer (score 4):

当方、専門はデザイナなんで、どこに表示するとかっていう仕様あればちゃちゃちゃっと作りましょうか。
作る上で、ロゴのデータとかあれば幸いです。

Comment: ロゴのデータ等を少々待ってください。使いやすいバージョンを探してみます。

Comment: 了解しました。ロゴデータはベクターのデータがあればBestです。

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/logos 日本語版がないけど、これを使えばいいと思います。

Comment: 内容確認しました。
他の解答みながら、728px x 90pxおよび220px x 250pxで何か作ってみましょう。

Answer (score 3):

広告の文言案ですが

- 答えが見つからない？ならここで投稿しよう、日本語で。
- 英語に疲れましたか？

<s>個人的には、妹がお兄ちゃんを心配するシチュエーションが良いです。</s>

Comment: とりあえず、この二つを利用して広告は作成中です。

Comment: わお、たのしみです。

Answer (score 2):

質問者も回答者も大歓迎

みたいな質問と回答の両方を募集する感じがあってもいいかもしれません。

Comment: 「質問者も回答者も大歓迎」そのままでいいですか？基本的に、向けたいオーディエンスはググルから検索で英語のサイトに入った人です。日本語のサイトの存在を知らない人に「日本語版を見てね！」という目的ですので、この文書でその効果があると是非適用したいと思っています。

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと切り口を変えて、回答者向けに「あなたの言語を温めよう」というアイデアはどうですかね。私自身、APIを育てる身としてSO以上のコミュニティーはないと思うので。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと受け狙いであれば、フリーザ様（有名なコミックのキャラクター）を出して
「私の信用度（せんとうりょく）は53万です」とやれば、年齢層的にかなり受けるんじゃないかなとか

Comment: 残念ながら、漫画のライセンスがないため、これは実現不可能です。

Answer (score 1):

「わからなかったら恥をかけ」というキャッチコピーでどうでしょう。

Comment: コミュニティがいいと思ったら、追加します！

Answer (score 0):

検索経由でたどり着いて、それでも解決しなかった人に対してのメッセージ案です。

```
「わからなければ、日本語で」
```