# 新しい広告を英語版に公開中

Tags: サポート, 広告

前に[広告のアイデアを募集しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361/stack-overflow%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%89%88%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%87%E3%82%A2%E5%8B%9F%E9%9B%86)。今週から新しい広告が日本のユーザーにメインサイトで公開し始めました：

[image: 日本語でok]
[image: 日本語でok]
[image: 答えが見つからない？ならここで投稿しよう、日本語で]
[image: 答えが見つからない？ならここで投稿しよう、日本語で]
[image: あなたの言語を温めよう]
[image: あなたの言語を温めよう]

アイデアありがとうございます。前の広告は非常にいい効果がありましたので、新しい広告により、日本語版を広げましょう。

Comment: 背景に入っている柄が雰囲気出てていいですね！