# 英語版Stack Overflowの広告更新

Tags: 討議, 広告

[image: 英語版のメインページ]

英語版Stack Overflowでの広告が旧式になってしまいました。

1. 広告の幅が広がりました
2. [ロゴの棒の本数が減りました](https://youtu.be/uipTZ2re4Uk)

2種類の広告があります：リーダーボード（質問の一番上）とサイドバー（メインページの右側）。現在の広告は[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1672)です。

多言語Stack Overflowの最新広告はこちらです（スペイン語ですが）：

- 答えが見つからない？ならここに投稿しよう、スペイン語で。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- 世界中に4億人がスペイン語を話す。自分の知識をスペイン語でシェアしたら？[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- スペイン語でok[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- プログラマー？なら自分の知識を共有しよう。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- 英語が読みたくない？スペイン語で参加しよう。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- 他のプログラマーたちをスペイン語で協力したい？ようこそ！[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の広告を日本語版にして使おうと思いますが、新しいアイデアや改善提案等があれば是非ご教示ください！

Comment: ポルトガル語版も面白いアイデアがありましたので、リンクを参考として添付します：http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5022/ajude-a-escolher-nossos-novos-banners-parte-2

Answer (score 3):

下記の５つをデザインチームにお願いする予定です：

- 答えが見つからない？ならここに投稿しよう、日本語で。
- 日本語でok
- プログラマー？なら自分の知識を共有しよう。
- 英語が読みたくない？日本語で参加しよう。
- 他のプログラマーたちと日本語で協力したい？ようこそ！

下記の広告は日本語に合わないと思いました：

> 世界中に4億人がスペイン語を話す。自分の知識をスペイン語でシェアしたら？

これを日本語にしたら下記のようなアイデアはどうかなと思いましたが、とりあえず上記の５つの広告で進む予定です。

> 日本は技術大国。日本の知識を日本語でシェアしよう。

Comment: 「他のプログラマーたちを日本語で協力したい？ようこそ！」は日本語として正しくすると「他のプログラマーたちと日本語で協力したい？ようこそ！」です（「を」を「と」に）。

Comment: 個人的には「日本語でok」だけでいいと思います。

Comment: @mjy 更新されました。広告を一つだけにすると、見えなくなる恐れがあります（同じ広告を繰り返すと、脳がそれを無視されちゃうことがあります）。現在５つとも使って、統計が集まれば更新・改善する予定です。それで大丈夫ですか？

Comment: なるほど、同じ広告ではだめなんですね。更新された物は日本語の間違いは無いです。

Comment: 最近だと技術より漫画・アニメで日本語に興味を持ったり覚えたりしている外国の方が多いような気がしますが、それをstackoverflowの広告で使うのは難しいですかね（自分は思いつかない）…

Comment: @packet0 アニメをそのまま利用すると著作権が難しくなりますが、その前に、外国人より、日本人向けの広告の方がいいんじゃないですか？