# オリジナルバナー作成について

Tags: 討議, 完了

参加くださったみなさま、どうもありがとうございました！

1. いつ訊くか？ 今、日本語版でしょ！ by payaneco
2. ペアプログラミングもベアプログラミングも英語もできない？よろしい、ならばスタック・オーバーフローだ。 by payaneco
3. 「誰かー!」「検索してもHITしないぞォォー!!」なぜなら!!! 誰も…まだ質問していないのである!!!! by payaneco
4. Rubyですか？日本語で質問できますよ！ by nekketsuuu
5. ねこです。英語はにがてです。よろしくおねがいします。――猫でもわかるスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版 by nekketsuuu
6. アナタハニホンゴチョットデキル by Phroneris
7. 最適化を無効化(-O0)すると動作しないアプリケーション？ by yohjp
8. Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？ by nekketsuuu

---

**スローガン投稿締切：2019年2月3日（日）**

留意点：
 - 既存の質問タイトル（プラス票が多いものなど）をバナーにという意見がございましたので、既存の質問投稿の単純エントリーも受け付けております。
 - 1)ご自身のアバター、2)ユーザーネーム、3)スローガンや質問のタイトルがバナー作成に使われます。

---

日本語を話すプログラマーの中にはまだスタック・オーバーフローの存在を知らない人がいるようです。そして、知っているけれどもあえてコミュニティに参加しないという人もいるようです。私たちは私たちのコミュニティをまだ知らないプログラマー仲間にこのコミュニティの存在を伝え、まだ参加できていないプログラマー仲間へは質問や回答の投稿をするように奨励すべきだと思います。なぜなら、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版への参加は、プロフェッショナルなプログラマーとしての成長に大きな影響を与えるからです。

これを行う最も簡単な方法の1つとして、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版と英語の本家Stack Overflow に日本語でのグラフィックバナーを表示することがあげられます。これらのバナーを使って、私たちはプログラマー仲間にスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版で質問や回答をするように奨励することができます。グラフィックバナーによってさらに知識深く且つ興味深いユーザーをサイトに迎え入れることができ、それがコミュニティの知識ベース作りに大きなプラスになると確信しています。

最高のバナーとはどのようなものでしょう? - 私たちが一緒に作り出すものです!

### 詳細

質問や回答をすることを奨励するバナーを一緒に作りましょう。アイデアやコメント、提案がある場合にはコミュニティで共有してください! 作業を少し簡単にするために、「スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版で質問しよう」というバナーを例にあげたいと思います。

#### どのようなバナーになりますか？

良いオリジナルバナーを作成するために以下を含めましょう:
1. ユーザーのプロフィール画像。 
2. サイト上で質問をすることに対するユーザーの個人的なアピール（スローガン）。 
3. 作成者のユーザー名 
4.「質問をしよう」等、行動を促すためのボタンの画像。

[スタック・オーバーフローロシア語版](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/6) で同じようなバナーを使い始めて約2年ほど経過しますが、非常に効果があります。

例:
[image]

<sub>スローガン: “答えが見つからない? どうぞ質問してください!”</sub>

#### 誰が参加できますか？

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のユーザー全員です！あなたのプロフィール写真としてGravatarを使っているのであれば問題ありません、大丈夫です。

#### スローガンの必要条件は何ですか？

1. 文章の独自性
2. 文章を読んだ人が行動を起こしたくなるようなものであること（質問を促すもの等）。
3. 文章は短く最大60文字（実はこの60文字というのが日本語でどうなのかわからないため様子をみさせてください）。
4. 既存の質問タイトル（プラス票が多いものなど）も、バナータイトルとして受け付けております！

#### バナーはどのように表示されますか?

以下の2つのサイトにてサイドバーと質問のタイトルの下に表示される予定です。

- Stack Overflow（英語の本家）
- スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版

#### バナーを準備するために何が必要ですか?

オリジナルバナー作成にはあなたのサポートが必要です! この質問の回答欄にスローガンを投稿して下さい。サイトでまだ質問をしていないプログラマー仲間へのアピールとなります。もしいくつかのスローガンを思いついた場合にはどうぞ全て（一つずつ）投稿してください。全てのスローガンを作成者のプロフィール画像及びユーザーネームとあわせてStack Exchange社のデザインチームに送り、彼らによってバナーが作成されます。

#### 何枚のバナーが使われますか?

8枚のバナーから始めたいと思います。沢山集まった場合には以下のクライテリアによって選択されます:

- スローガンの独自性
- 回答欄に投稿された時間（先に投稿されたものが選ばれます）

提案やコメントがある場合にはこちらの質問の*コメント欄*に投稿ください。

**プロフェッショナルなプログラマーとしての成長の第一歩を踏み出せるよう、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版コミュニティへの参加を促しましょう!**

---

payanecoさんとnekketsuuuさんの質問とNicさんの回答に基づき以下追記（2019/01/22)

1. オリジナルバナーでの呼び名は「スタック・オーバーフロー」でも「スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版」でも「日本語版」だけでもよろしいかと思います。ご自身のスローガンにぴたっとくるものをご使用ください。
2. スローガンの英訳はされません。日本語のみです。
3. 「オタクっぽい」スローガンだとしても、個人の良識の範囲であれば大丈夫です。
4. 質問者や回答者の誘致はもちろんのこと、その他のアイデアが浮かんだ方はどうぞ一度ご投稿ください。
5. プロフィール画像はご自身の顔写真でなくても問題ありません。現在使用されているアバターがそのままバナー作成に使用されます。

---

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki?tab=profile) for the translation!

Comment: 広告の掲載先がSO内であるなら、リーチするのは「まだSOの存在を知らない人」ではなく「知っているけど敢えてコミュニティに参加していない人」になる気がします。

Comment: @cubick たしかにそうですね、少し編集させて下さい m_ _m

Comment: わたしの身の回りでは「日本語版って日本語で質問して良かったの？！」ということを言っていた人が複数いたので、日本語でQ&Aができるということをアピールできれば良いのかなと思いました。

Comment: 参考：Nicolas さんに伺ったところ、既にある「日本語でok」などの広告とは別扱いの広告になるそうです。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2193/19110

Comment: (I'm sorry for writing in English) @nekketsuuu we can try different slogans, thought I personally think that banners leading to the ask question page the best one. The main difference of this campaign is that it assumes users' personal recommendations to ask on SOja. I think it's very important to show that SOja it's not just a site, it's a community, real people.

Comment: 過去のメタ投稿で[「ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/19110)というのがあるのですが、ここでは「日本語版」と言ってしまうのでしょうか？（もし可能なら、その方が分かりやすいと思います）　／　An old meta-post in 2014 says that we don't call this site "Japanese version" for a branding strategy, however here do we write SO**ja**? I think it's better to write "Japanese SO" if possible in order to emphasize a fact that we ask questions in Japanese in this site.

Comment: バナーという単語は「横断幕」程度の意味しかなく、ここに「広告」を付けてしまうと『他サイトに掲載するためのバナー広告募集』のようなイメージになってしまいます。SOjaおよびSO(=自サイト内)で掲載するのであれば、単にバナーや告知、広報くらいの方が誤解しないのかなと思いました。

Comment: @cubick バナー、オリジナルバナー作成、といたしました！ありがとうございます :)

Comment: @nekketsuuu 仰るとおりです！ありがとうございます、和訳を明確にするため、ここしばらくは「スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版」としておりました...。これまでにもいくつかご意見があったようですし、翻訳支援の chat room で少し確認作業ができればと思います。payanecoさんの「よろしい。ならばスタックオーバーフロー日本語版だ」と「そこのアナタ、スタック・オーバーフローで活躍しませんか？」と、どちらもカッコよくて甲乙つけ難くなってしまいました(^_^;)

Comment: @aki ありがとうございます。「ちくしょう。日本語版だ！」というスローガンも思い付いてしまい、私の中で収拾がつかなくなっています。

Comment: なんとパンチの効いた Σ（・□・；）ちなみに、ツイッターアカウント名は 「Stack Overflow 日本語版」となっているようですね

Answer (score 4):

締切日までにたくさんのスローガン案が投稿されますように。

私のスローガン案を下記で確定させていただきます。
何だかノリと勢いだけで投稿している感もありますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

1. いつ訊くか？今、日本語版でしょ！
2. ペアプログラミングもベアプログラミングも英語もできない？
   よろしい、ならばスタック・オーバーフローだ。
3. 「誰かー!」「検索してもHITしないぞォォー!!」
   なぜなら!!!誰も…まだ質問していないのである!!!!
4. 英語よりC(\+{2}|#)?言語が得意なそこのアナタ、日本語版で活躍しませんか？

---

とても素敵な取り組みですね！
是非たくさんの投稿があるように期待しております。

さてスローガンを考えてみたところ、いくつか質問を思い付きました。
まずは思い付いたスローガンを日本語で提示します。

1. ペアプログラミングもベアプログラミングもできない？
   よろしい。ならばスタックオーバーフロー日本語版だ。
2. おとなもこどもも、ハッカーさんも
   質問するまで、泣くんじゃない。
3. 英語よりC(\+{2}|#)?言語が得意なそこのアナタ、スタック・オーバーフローで活躍しませんか？

以下が質問です。

1. スローガンの中で「スタックオーバーフロー日本語版」はどのように表記するのが望ましいでしょうか。
   英語で「ja.stackoverflow」、カタカナで「スタック・オーバーフロー」などの表記はどれもOKですか？
2. `英語の本家Stack Overflow にスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のグラフィックバナー広告を表示する`とのことですが、英訳はされない前提で投稿してよろしいですね？
3. 2番目は日本で有名なキャッチコピーの改変です。
   元ネタがあるものやいわゆる「オタクっぽい」ものを、個人の良識の範囲で挙げても許容されますか？
4. 3番目は回答者にフォーカスを当てています。
   今回のスローガンはあくまで質問者の誘致を重視していると考えて良いですか？
5. 私はプロフィールも画像も設定していませんが、その時点で投稿は遠慮する方が良いでしょうか？

---

(I'm sorry for translating into Japlish)
This is very good plan!
I expect many slogans to be posted.

When I thought about the slogan, I came up with some questions.
First, I present some slogans which I came up with in Japanese.

1. ペアプログラミングもベアプログラミングもできない？
   よろしい。ならばスタックオーバーフロー日本語版だ。
2. おとなもこどもも、ハッカーさんも
   質問するまで、泣くんじゃない。
3. 英語よりC(\+{2}|#)?言語が得意なそこのアナタ、スタック・オーバーフローで活躍しませんか？

Next, I have questions.

1. How is it good to describe "スタックオーバーフロー日本語版" in the slogan?
   Are there no problem with descriptions like "ja.stackoverflow"(in English) or "スタック・オーバーフロー"(in Katakana)?
2. I read `(One of the easiest way is )Display the SOja's graphic banner ad on SOcom` in this question.
   Don't we need to think about translate English the slogans?
3. The second imitates a famous catch copy in Japan.
   Can I post anything like that or "geeky" one?
4. The third is for respondents.
   Do we make slogans to invite questioners?
5. I have not set profiles and images. So I should not post slogans?

Comment: (Sorry for writing in English) Thank you for the reply and your questions. Let me start from the end. Please do post slogans regardless of what type of profile images you use. The main idea of using the author's profile image is to show that we are community, real people, not just content. I think Gravatar images are common and well recognised as a person's profile picture. Let us post any slogans we think might catch a readers' attention either "geeky" or not and directed to users who want to ask or answer.

Comment: When we have the banners ready we can choose with which we want to start and then just look at the stats in order to understand what works what does not. If I get the second question right, I think the we are going to have banners in Japanese only for both sites (SOja, SOen). The first question is completely up to the community. [I shared what we have decided on SOru in a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48541367#48541367). Could you please take a look? Please share what do you think?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Thank you for your answers! The answers solved my questions. I hope many SOja users will post slogans!

Comment: @payaneco  確定くださりありがとうございます！1)からの優先順位という理解でよろしいでしょうか？全体の応募者数にもよりますが、payanecoさんのスローガンを例えば2つ採用させていただく場合、1)いつ訊くか？今、日本語版でしょ！、2)ペアプログラミングもベアプログラミングも英語もできない？よろしい、ならばスタック・オーバーフローだ。と上から2つ使用させていただければと..。もしも思い入れのあるスローガンなど、ございましたらぜひお教えくださいませm_ _m。（確定版で、ハッカーさんいなくなりましたね..。）

Comment: @aki ご返信ありがとうございます。1)からの優先順位で受けが良いのではないかと想定して列挙しております。特に思い入れはありませんので、どれでも使いやすいものをご利用いただければと存じます。よろしくお願いいたします。(ハッカーさんは「質問するまで～」がしっくり来なかったので除外しました。SOユーザとM〇ther2の親和性は高い気もしますが…。

Answer (score 3):

#### 案

- アナタハニホンゴチョットデキル

#### 解説

「ワタシハ◯◯チョットデキル」は、そのスキルにとても長けていることを表すミームです。
私が調べた限りでは、一番の元ネタはプルシェンコ氏の「ワタシハスケートチョットデキル」です。その後リーナス氏が「ワタシハリナックスチョットデキル」と書かれたTシャツを着たのが大きく話題になり、以後プログラミングなどの専門的・技術的分野のスペシャリストを指す言葉として定着したようです。
それを借用して「あなたは日本語が母語なんだから、日本語で使えるサービスを使おうぜ」と呼びかけるのがこのスローガンです。

#### 参考リンク

- [エンジニアの言う「完全に理解した」「なにもわからない」「チョットデキル」って本当はこういう意味？「わかる」の声多数 - Togetter](https://togetter.com/li/1268851)
- [ROBAさんのツイート: "プルシェンコの「ワタシハスケートチョットデキル」がチョットデキルの元祖と書いたら「ワタシハリナックスチョットデキル」が元祖じゃないのか、と書いてる人が居たので調べた。プルシェンコは2014年2月中旬で、5月に行われたLINUXCONで配られたのがTシャツがLinuxらしい。"](https://twitter.com/vjroba/status/914553781798436866)
- [チョットデキル until:2010-12-31 -source:easybotter - Twitter検索](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%87%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%20until%3A2010-12-31%20-source%3Aeasybotter&src=typd)

Answer (score 2):

#### スローガン案

1. 日本語で質問したい方はこちら
2. Rubyですか？　日本語で質問できますよ！
3. ねこです。英語はにがてです。よろしくおねがいします。――猫でもわかるスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版

   - [SCP-040-JP](http://ja.scp-wiki.net/scp-040-jp) と[猫でもわかるプログラミング](http://www.kumei.ne.jp/c_lang/)のパロディです
4. 回答が良く分からない？　日本語で説明しますよ！

#### 実際の質問タイトルを使う?

実際の質問のタイトルに合わせたバナーも作りたいというお話もあった気がするので、いくつか案を挙げてみます。いくつかは私のアイコンだと不自然ですが……。

- [コマンドが終了したら音を鳴らしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/230/19110)

  - [ツアー](/tour)で使われている質問です。
- [２次元配列は不連続か？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5022/19110)

  - 回答が承認されている質問の中では2019年1月現在最も vote 結果が高い質問です。
  - 内容としても「英語が分からなかったから日本語で質問する」というものです。
- [Python の A, B = B, A とはなに？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48551/19110)

  - 私の回答の中で最も vote 結果が高い回答をつけることができた質問です。
- [PATH とは何ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/37237/19110)
- [Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/19110)
- [リストの末尾 n 個を取り出したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46711/19110)

  - 私の質問の中で閲覧数が大きいものたちです。自己回答も含みます。

Comment: 素晴らしいものたちをいくつもありがとうございます！1)「Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？」、2)「Rubyですか？日本語で質問できますよ！」、3)「ねこです。英語はにがてです。よろしくおねがいします。――猫でもわかるスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版」、という優先順位でもよろしいでしょうか？全体の応募者数にもよりますが念のため..。

Comment: @aki さん、OKです :)

Comment: 列挙されている [２次元配列は不連続か？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5022/) は良くも悪くも「マニアック」過ぎるので、込み入った質問が求められていると誤解を招く／意図しない萎縮効果があるのかもと懸念しています。良く解釈すれば、こういう突っ込んだ質問をしてもOKとも取れますので、個々人で解釈は異なると思いますが一応コメントまで。

Answer (score 2):

チャットにて [推薦頂いた](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48804834#48804834) 質問を挙げておきます。

- [最適化を無効化(-O0)すると動作しないアプリケーション？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22446/)

Answer (score 1):

#### 案

- プログラミングの質問が！！！！
  英語じゃなくて日本語でできる！！！！！！
  嬉しい！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！

#### 解説

「情報が！」の方とほぼ同じものですが、あちらが検索者視点なのに対し、こちらは参加者視点です。
理想としては両方を1つのコピーに集約すべきですしそうしたかったのですが、それをやった結果が盛大な文字数オーバーでしたので、いっそ分割しました。
私がこの企画に気付いたのが昨日でなければ、もっと熟考できたかもしれませんが…。口惜しいです。

Comment: ご連絡が遅くなってしまいましたが、限られた時間内にたくさんご投稿いただき誠にありがとうございましたm_ _m。参加者視点でのスローガンが嬉しかったです！しかし残念ながら今回はこちらは採用に至りませんでした...。（チョットデキルの方が採用されまして、現在デザインチームが作成中です！）

Comment: ありがとうございます。1つでも採用されたのは大変嬉しいです。ただ、この企画については正直に申し上げますと不満が2つあります…。1つはやはりタイトルがわかりづらいことです。当時は『投稿締切は2/3（日）です＼(^o^)／！オリジナルバナー作成について』というタイトルでしたが、私が最初にそれを見て想像したのは、「デザイナーやイラストレーターにバナー画像（何の？）を作ってもらって、PNG辺りの画像ファイルとして提出してもらうようなことを募集しているのかな」でした。これが『スローガン募集！ 日本語版バナー作成ご協力のお願い』みたいなタイトルだったらもっと要件が明確になり、集まりが良かったのではないかと思います。もう1つは細かいことですが、`もしいくつかのスローガンを思いついた場合にはどうぞ全て（一つずつ）投稿してください。`という要項がありながら、実際には1つの回答に複数のスローガン案を併記することがまかり通っていたことです。要項の時点で内容がわかりづらいのにその要項すら守られていないというのは、個人的にはかなり混乱しました。まあ提案だけでなく質問なども兼ねて回答機能がファジーに使われていたからというのもあると思いますし、あるいは上記のルールは募集開始当初には無かったとかなのかもしれませんが、何にせよ以後類似の企画があるとしたら改善を祈ります。

Comment: ご意見どうもありがとうございます、次回はタイトルをもっとわかりやすくさせていただきたいと思いますm_ _m（次回もこのようなスタイルになるかどうかは全く未定なのですが『スローガン募集！日本語版バナー作成ご協力のお願い』に近いものを♡）尚、1つの回答に複数のスローガン案が併記されたのはそれと同時に質問や提案をいただいたのが理由であったように思えます。

Answer (score 0):

#### 案

- プログラミングの情報が！！！！
  英語じゃなくて日本語で見つかる！！！！！
  嬉しい！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！

#### 解説

ただのプリミティブなド直球です。
3行にわたる表現がそのまま掲載可能なのかわかりませんが、もし不可能なら改行を半角または全角のスペース1つで置換してください。つまり、（`！英`ではなく）`！ 英`または`！　英`のようになることを希望します。私個人としては半角の方が好みですが、そちらの日本語スタイルガイドにお任せします。
ちなみに原案は

> プログラミングの情報を検索したら英語じゃなくて日本語の記事が出てくるの嬉しいな～！！ 皆もっと日本語で質問や回答してその母数を増やしてくれたらもっと嬉しいんだけどな～！！！（ﾁﾗｯﾁﾗｯ

でしたが、あまりにも文字数オーバーでした。

Answer (score 0):

#### 案

- 日本語版サイトで質問すると、日本語で質問できます。
  しかも、日本語で回答が来ます。

#### 解説

そのままです。そのまますぎる様をナンセンスじみたジョークにしたものです。
しかし、Stack Overflowを英語のプログラミング情報集サイトだと思っているような人が英語記事内でこのスローガンを見つけた場合、「日本語専用版があるんだ」ということと「誰かがこの（今開いている英語の）質問をしたのと同じように、自分も質問者側に回り得るんだ」ということを明確に認識させる効果もあると思っています。
まあ、「コピー機使わせてください」より「コピー機使いたいのでコピー機使わせてください」の方が成功率が上がる、みたいなものかもしれませんが。
ちなみに原案は

> 日本語版サイトで質問すると、運気が上がり、背が伸び、恋人ができ、百万円手に入っ…たりはしませんが、日本語で質問できます。

でしたが、コンプライアンスが叫ばれる昨今ではちょっと綱渡りなのでやめました。