# コミュニティバナーが掲載されました！

Tags: 討議

A lot of thanks to [@cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick) for the translation!

---

2019年3月8日(金)より、コミュニティバナーが掲載されました。[参加してくれた皆さん](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2915/78)に感謝します。バナーは、間違いなくスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のコミュニティに、より多くの注目を集める手助けとなるでしょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ご質問、ご提案、ご意見がありましたら、遠慮なくコミュニティで共有してください。

Comment: Also thanks Nic-san, aki-san and related designers!

Comment: that's really good banners! thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

バナー8枚のスクリーンショットです☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 出来上がったバナーが一覧に並ぶと壮観ですね。まとめ、ありがとうございます。