# コミュニティバナーの文がダークモードだと読めない

Tags: バグ, 調査中, 広告, ダークモード

現在、StackOverflowとその他言語版では、ユーザーが設定でダークモードを選択できます。その場合、一部のバナーの文字が背景の色と近くなり、読めなくなります。読めなくなるバナーは、スタック・オーバーフロー（日本語版StackOverflow）の宣伝として作られた[コミュニティバナー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2954/3054)のようです。

例:

> [image: バナー]
>
> [image: バナー]
>
> [image: バナー]

対処としては、背景の透過をやめて、色で埋めることが考えられます。他のバナーはそうしているようです。

例:

> [image: 透過でないバナーの例]

---

#### 追記: 2023-06-05

スペイン語版でも同じ現象を確認しました。（日本語版は、[広告欄が空白になる問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3873/3054)が続いており、ダークモードの問題を確認できる状態では無いです）

例:

> [image: スペイン語版バナー]

Comment: この件は修正されました。もしもダークモードでまた見づらくなってしまった場合、キャッシュをクリアして再度ご確認ください。まだ問題がある場合には、私にメンションを飛ばすなどしてどうぞお知らせください。

Comment: @SpencerG 　延期タグを削除してくださりありがとうございます。本件の修正につきまして目視確認が未だできません。現在ダークモードとライトモードの両方で、全て黒あるいは白一色のものが表示されてしまっています。広告の報告を行いましたので再度デザインチームに修正依頼をお願いします。修正の目視確認後に完了タグを追加いたします。

Comment: @SpencerG 広告のスペースが空白になっており、この件の修正も確認できません。
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3873/3054 にてスクリーショットを添付します。
（既に aki さんのコメントで指摘されている内容と同じと思います）

Answer (score 4):

ダークモードは2020年6月に正式に [実装](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits) されましたが、日本語版でコミュニティバナーを作成したのは2019年3月です。そのため、Stack Exchange サイトで表示されている多数の広告の中で、ダークモード実装以降に作られたバナーは背景が白ですが、それ以前のものは透明で作られたものが多かったためダークモードでは見辛くなってしまっているのが現状です。

現時点での改善策としては、バナーの右下にある「この広告を報告」をクリックしてプロダクトチーム（プロダクトマネージャー」にリーチすることがあげられるとのことです。広告の報告を行うことを私の方から続けてゆこうと思います。更新時期は未定と聞いています。

Comment: 我々で作った広告ですし、我々の側からクリエイティブの更新を促すことはできないのでしょうか？　SE 社内で直通で会話できるのではないかと思ったのですが……。

Comment: 提案されている「広告の報告」は、あくまで (本当の意味での) 出稿された広告の問題を報告するための手段です。コミュニティバナーについては文面のアイデアこそユーザーが出したものですが、バナー画像は SE 社内で作成したものなはずで、修正も SE 社内で完結するはずです。 / どのタイミングで表示されるか分からないものをユーザーに報告させるのは筋違いだと思います。 (繰り返し報告が殺到してスタッフの手を煩わせる可能性もあります)

Comment: @nekketsuuu SE 社内で直通の依頼が可能な体制ではないようで、大変申し訳ありません。プロダクトチームに更新を促すためには「広告の報告を行うことが必要である」と昨日CMのニックさんより口頭で回答があり、コミュニティマネジメントチームからプロダクトチームへ直接の依頼をしてもらえないことに私自身が驚いたものの、現在の時点での対応策は「広告の報告」のみと回答をもらえましたためそのように投稿いたしました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 「我々の側からクリエイティブの更新を促す」という「我々」とはバナー作成に参加くださった4名の方を意味されますでしょうか、それともSOjaという意味でしょうか。齟齬がないように確認させてください。

Comment: SOja です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ユーザーとしての私の考えでは、akiさんが「広告の報告」を継続する必要は無いです。
私も報告はしないと思います（一度くらいはするかも知れませんが）。
既に行なっていただいた報告を見て、担当の方が他の画像にも対応して下さるかも知れません。
また、ガバナンスの問題を労力で補ってしまうと、ガバナンスの崩壊が止まりません。
折に触れ、社内の連絡が回復したか ping する程度でよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  SOja 全体として更新を促すというお言葉嬉しく思います、ありがとうございます。ここスタック・オーバーフローは以前 Yuki さんが作ってくださったバナーにありましたが「開発者の、開発者による、開発者のための Q&A サイト」であり、ユーザーのみなさんのためのコミュニティです。本投稿およびみなさんからの投票がもととなり（広告の報告はいくつか済みましたので）クリエイティブの更新を促せているのだと思います。

Comment: @みなさま  CM のかたも、もちろん私自身も、SOja が今後もさらに成長して行けるように SOja と同じ側にいます。反対側で何かをブロックしようとしているわけでは決してありません。プロダクトチームへ SOja から直通できるものが「広告の報告」であり、今回のアドバイスは直通最速ルートであったからなのだと思います。（例えばコミュニティマネジメントチーム内で Jira、トリアージ、討議や連絡、といった過程をスキップしてプロダクトチームへ直通連絡できたことなど。）もしも私が広告の報告をご案内したことによって気分を悪くされた方がおられましたら、申し訳ありません。時期は未定ですがプロダクトチームから連絡がありましたら再度ご連絡させてください。