# 広告が正常に表示されていません

Tags: バグ, 調査中, 広告

現在、広告の内容が表示されず、空白になっています。[別質問のコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3759/#comment3935_3759)で指摘されているのも、この現象だと思います。

スクリーンショット:

> [image: 広告の表示の様子]