# 広告表示のバグ修正に向けた情報収集に協力してください

Tags: 討議, バグ, 広告

[ご覧になったこと](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3759/14055) があるかもしれませんが、一部のバナーやサイドバー広告が適切に表示されないという厄介なバグが、残念ながら未だに継続しています。私たちはこのバグを再現するためにテストを行ってきましたが成功に至りません。

そのため、協力をいただける方がおられないかと、ここに投稿させていただきました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もしも時間のある方がおられましたら、「この広告を報告」をクリックし「その他」を選択、以下の情報を記していただけると幸いです。

- ブラウザの種類とバージョン
- マシンの種類 (Mac, Windows, iPhone, Androird など)
- OS
- VPNの使用？

これらの情報が集まれば、問題の原因について一歩前進し、解決できるのではないかと考えます。ご不便をおかけし申し訳ありませんが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 報告時には問題のある広告画像を添付するように求められますが、画像が表示されないのが問題なので、(自分で取得した) 画面キャプチャでも OK なのでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick はいそうです、バナー広告かどうかを判断したいのです。/ Correct we want to be able to tell if its a banner ad or not.

Comment: Firefox だと、この広告を報告の画面で "Share diagnostic information" にチェックボックスを入れると送信できなくなります。（navigator.userAgentDataを取得しようとしていますが、Firefox は対応していないため、エラーになるためです）

Comment: Is the issue @YujiSoftware pointed out understood within Stack Exchange? Need translation into English?

Comment: @mjy Yes, this issue occurs with Stack Overflow, etc. Please report it in English as well.

Comment: I also posted YujiSoftware's report [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396672/).
I think it's best not to ignore this issue.

Answer (score 2):

追記 2024-02-09:
YujiSoftwareさんにコメントで報告いただいていた問題は、他サイトでも再現するようなので、[Meta Stack Exchangeでも報告](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396672/report-ad-with-diagnostic-information-fails-in-firefox)しました。

この問題は重要であり、無視するべきでは有りません。なぜなら、不具合が発生する環境を特定しようとしているのに、特定の環境からは不具合が報告されていないのですから、間違った前提の上に検証を行なうことになるからです。

---

[広告が正常に表示されていません](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3873/3054) においてご報告した際や、その後にテストした環境は以下です。

- OS: Linux、Windows、Mac
- ブラウザ: Firefox、Chrome、Edge、Safari、その他
- アクセス元IPアドレス: 日本/東京、アメリカ合衆国/西部及び中央
- ブラウザの言語設定: 日本語、英語

ご覧の通り、ある程度は網羅的にテスト済みです。キャッシュの有無、ログイン状態なども複数の状態でテストしています。

また空白になる広告ですが、「一部」では無く、ほとんど常に、ほとんど全てです。もしかすると、正常に表示されるケースを収集する方が効率的で有意義かも知れません。

元々、このサイト（Stack Overflow日本語版）においては広告が表示される頻度が少ないので、かなりの時間を伴なう検証でした。これを再度行ない、それぞれの環境下で「報告」ボタンをクリックするという作業を行なうつもりはありません。この回答をもって報告とさせて下さい。