# 2020：あけましておめでとうございます！

Tags: サポート

翻訳をしてくれた[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)に感謝します。

---

過ぎ行く年はせわしなく、コミュニティにとっても Stack Exchange 社にとっても難しい年でした。昨年、私たちはいくつかのとても重要な議題を成功裏に収めました。

- 「[大切にしたい価値観](/help/key-values)」と「[マニフェスト](/help/manifesto)」について議論し、ヘルプセンターに記事を追加しました。
- [MeetUpを開催しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/78)。
- [コミュニティのバナー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2915/78)を制作しました。

他にも色々です！　これからも続けていきましょう！

#### 数字で見る1年

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | スタック・          |  スタック・        |
|                    | オーバーフロー      |  オーバーフロー     |
|                    | 2018               |  2019             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  質問              |     5 236          |    4 998          |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  回答              |     4 547          |    4 146          |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  新規ユーザー       |     4 656          |    4 553          |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### 未来に向けて

- **ユーザーからのフィードバックへ更に注意を払う**。私の知る限り、サイトに参加する体験を良くするため、[我が社はしっかりとした方針を取りました](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/)。コミュニティからのフィードバックに基づいて改善を行うということはとても重要です。もちろんサイト開設当初からユーザーのアイディアを基に意思決定をしてきましたが、今年はサイトへの考えを共有する機会がより増えることでしょう。サイトの変化について何か思うところがあれば、それを実装するとても良い時期です！
- **配信、MeetUp、コンテスト**、その他いろいろなことをして「コミュニティを作ります」。今年はもっとたくさんのイベントを開けたら良いなと思っています。
- **プロジェクトのミッションに集中する**。我々の注意を我々のミッション（コミュニティにナレッジベースを作ること）から逸らすようなことを良い悪い関わらずすべて避けれれば、サイトはより速く成長し、体験がより楽しくなることでしょう。これを達成するひとつの方法は、野心的なゴールを作り、それを成し遂げるためにできることをすべてすることです。

この10年、ITの世界は大きく変わりました。2010年、最初のバージョンのAndroid OS上で "Hello World!" を出力するプロジェクトをビルドする方法を探し出すためには数日を要しました。いまとなっては、SNSで配信される音楽をとってきて車内で再生するアプリをJavaScriptで書くのに数時間あれば足ります。コミュニティ自身も変わりました。全ての側面において。この5年、この100%ポジティブな変化を生み出す触媒に私たち全員がなれたことを非常に嬉しく思います。本当にありがとうございます！ =)

#### スタック・オーバーフローは我々のことです！　互いに祝福しましょう！

一緒に祝福しましょう！　コミュニティの歴史からあなたの個人的な記憶に至るまで、あなたが最も嬉しかったポジティブなイベントを共有してください。もし過去にどなたかユーザーがあなたの生活を良くしたのであれば、是非彼ら彼女らを祝福し、質問への回答で感謝を述べましょう。あなたの気付きを嬉しく思ってくれることでしょう。

[image: クリスマスツリー]

**[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)の皆さんに多大なる感謝を！　あけましておめでとう！　皆様のご多幸をお祈りします。新年に皆さんにお会いできること、嬉しく思います！　たくさんの興味深いことが私たち全員を待っています！ =)**