# Stack Overflow日本語版、公開ベータへ

Tags: 討議

プライベートベータユーザーのみなさんお疲れさまでした。おかげさまで2週間で140以上の質問、240以上の回答が集まり、ユーザー数は約1200人になりました。

予想以上に反響がよく、1日でも早く公開したいとのコメントが[スポルスキ社長](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD)からありました。そのため、今日からプライベートベータからパブリックベータへ移行しました。

下記にアナウンス関連のブログや記事をまとめます。他にも見つけたら、編集で足してください：

- [Stack Overflowブログ記事](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/)
- [ジョエル・スポルスキのツイッター](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/544647825666351105)
- [publickeyブログ](http://www.publickey1.jp/blog/14/stack_overflow_2.html)
- [はてなブックマーク](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/#tw?u=epokhee)

Stack Overflowを広めるのに一番効果的なのは口コミです。

- SNS（Facebook, Google+, Twitterなど）
- [Qiita](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281/30)
- [スラッシュドットやReddit日本語版](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/282/30)

などで周囲の開発者に伝えていただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。