# パブリックベータ開始から2ヶ月、スタックオーバーフローはどうですか？

Tags: 討議

Stack Overflow日本語版が[パブリックベータとしてオープン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1410/30)してから早くも2ヶ月が経ち、その間たくさんの質問を解決してきました。

<sup>既に質問文は読んだので回答をチェックしたい[→回答にジャンプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1695/%E3%83%91%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E9%96%8B%E5%A7%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%892%E3%83%B6%E6%9C%88-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#answers)</sup>

[image: 2ヶ月間の統計]
<sup>Stack Exchangeチームからいただきました。</sup>

これを機に、一息ついて全体を振り返ることができる場を設けたいと思います。システム上、6ヶ月おきに[サイトの自己評価](http://stackexchange.com/filters/27261/site-evaluations?sort=newest)をする仕組みがあり、そのちょっとした先取りです。

Stack Overflowの目的、[「プログラミングに関する質問について、インターネットを通してより多くのエキスパートから回答を得られる場を提供する事」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/30)[「プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問に対する詳細な回答集を作ること」](/tour)をふまえて、

- **よかったこと**
- **もっとよくできること**
- **改善点として今後やってみたいこと**

は何かあるでしょうか。個人的な振り返りでも、全体的な傾向で感じている何か、モデレーターへのフィードバックなどでも大丈夫です。普段は言う機会がなくて胸にしまっていたようなことも、ぜひ回答としてシェアしてみてください。

なお、より実のある振り返りとするために、以下のことにご留意ください。

- 問題点があれば、それで終わることなく、解決方法を一緒にポジティブに考えていきましょう
- 個人攻撃にならないよう注意しましょう

<sup>[「ポストモーテムしていますか？――Web サイト情報戦略シリーズ（1）」](http://internetcom.jp/busnews/20040617/8.html)より抜粋・編集</sup>

振り返りのお供としていくつかデータを載せます。

- 質問数: **1,370**
- 回答数: **2,308**
- 投票数: **9,395**
- 使われているタグの数: **628** （2回以上使われているタグの数: **269**）
- ユーザー数: **5,108**
- こなしたレビューの数: **1,803**
- メタで討議タグが付いた質問の数: **43**
- 質問が投稿されてからプラス票付きの回答が投稿されるまでの時間: **70分**

<sup>（12月16日のパブリックベータ公開から2ヶ月間の合計。タグの数は現時点のもの。最後の統計は先週の中央値）</sup>

[1日あたりの質問・回答・投票数のグラフ](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/revision/259299/358544/questions-answers-and-votes-per-day?StartDate=2014-12-16#graph):

[image: 週末は少なくなる?]

[Stack Exchangeの各サイトの規模をツリーマップで可視化したもの](http://bl.ocks.org/ento/568dad1045ff25d376e1/):

[image: たくさんのQ&Aサイト]
<sup>日本語版の運営日数はプレアルファ期間を含みます。</sup>  
<sup>こうしてみると、1日あたりの質問数は数年先輩のQ&Aサイトとも肩を並べるほどですね。</sup>

Comment: 信用度を捨てたので回答でコメントします。
その内のどれだけがクローズされました？

Comment: @natsukitinyak [20件のクローズ質問があります](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Atrue)

Comment: @natsukitinyak 今週日曜くらいまでの統計で、18件がクローズ、またクローズ後再オープンされたものが13件ありました。[こちらのSEDEクエリ](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/edit/277712#resultSets)で1つずつ確認できます。 (Resultsタブをクリックすると質問数 → クローズ理由の合計 → 個々の質問の一覧で結果を切り替えられます)

Answer (score 9):

個人的な振り返りです。

### よかったこと

人の助けになるようなことができたこと。それも、自分のちょっとした空き時間を使った人助けなのでなおさらです。私の回答を読んで、賛成票をつけてくださったり、承認済みとしてくださったり、読みやすいように編集してくださったりと、さまざまな助けがあってこれまでやってこれました。この場を借りて感謝いたします。ありがとうございます。

### 改善点として今後やってみたいこと

SOは助け合いで成り立っていると個人的には考えております。回答する側が質問した側を助ける形になるのはSOのフローとして当然ですが、質問をする側が回答する側の助けになるようになることをアウトプットできるような助けができればいいなぁと思っています。
SOでは、質問に対してのアクションとして反対票を投じたり、クローズ票を投じたりと、マイナスなアクションを比較的簡単に行うことができてしまいます。私自身も、回答することが難しいと感じられたものにはマイナスアクションをしてしまいがちなのですが、一歩踏み込んで、可能ならば質問者に質問を改善していただくために具体的な指針となるコメントをしたいなぁと考えています。

Answer (score 9):

### よかったこと

ちょっとタグ追加が必要じゃないか？と思う質問がありまして。しかし自分の信用度が足りないために、コメントでタグ追加して欲しいと要望したらパパっと追加されまして。　見てくれている人がいるんだなと安心しました。

### もっとよくできること＆改善点として今後やってみたいこと

コメントに必要な信用度50は、英語版と同じ基準だと思いますが。
日本語版だけスタートアップ期間として、一時的に下げることはできないものでしょうか。
というのも……新しいユーザーがある質問に興味を持って、回答もしたいのに、必要なコメント質問（条件や要求目的などの確認など）もできないと、不便を感じるのではないかと少し懸念しています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！英語版ではコメントをフォラムと同じように使う人が多かったため、５０信用度以上に制限させました。それは正しいとは言わないですが、制限の考え方です。

Comment: @jmac そういう背景があったのですね。まあ確かにコメントから解決してしまうのも現状でもありますが。私の懸念は、今では情報共有サービスが数多く存在するので自分の知っていることを配信するだけでは魅力を感じない人がいるのではないかと心配した次第です。　具体例を一案申し上げると正式から3ヶ月ぐらい30(承認済2個分/賛成票3個分)とか。　ああでも50に満たいない人が3ヶ月後くかもしれないという懸念もありますね。簡単にいきませんね。

Comment: その気持もわかります。はじめの頃からフォラムと違って会話を避けたいためにコメントを制限させました。一部のユーザーに不便とわかっても、今まで会話を避けるのを優先的にしました。ある理由で日本語版のコメント信用度を低く設定しても掲示板のようにならないとの提案があれば、別のメタ投稿を投稿してくれますか？

Comment: @jmac (う。今気づいた。 3ヶ月後く→3ヶ月後驚く) 私自身まだ日本語版に来て間もなくて、様子を見てみたいというのと。このトピックでは、ぼーっと頭に思いついたことをバスケットに放り込んだだけな感じなので。改めて必要そうに感じたら提案トピックを起こしてみます。　コメントありがとう。

Answer (score 2):

いくつかのタグで質問があったらメールで通知が来るように設定しているのですが、
メールの text/plain パート中のURLが途中で改行されてしまう問題を修正してほしいです。

例えば次のようになります。(「ap」と「ache2」の間で改行されてしまっている)

```
[Apache2
でパスワード保護したディレクトリにロボットが侵入](<http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6801/ap
ache2>)
```

text/html パート中は大丈夫です。

```
                    <a href="http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6801/apache2" style="color: #0077cc; text-decoration: none;">Apache2 でパスワード保護したディレクトリにロボットが侵入</a>
```

text/plain パート内の URL の途中で改行が挿入されないようにならないでしょうか。

Comment: バグ？報告のようですが、この質問へ回答する代わりに別途質問されてはいかがでしょうか？ http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @unarist バグを投稿しなくても、とりあえず開発者に報告しました。@fumiyas 追加質問があれば、ここにコメントを載せます。メール通知を十分テストしていない可能性はだいぶ高いです。

Comment: A fix rolled out with [se] build rev 2015.3.30.1248.