# 祝スタック・オーバーフロー公開5周年

Tags: 討議, 交流会

スタック・オーバーフローは本日、[公開](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1410/14055)から5周年を迎えることができました。質問や回答、編集や投票、そして日々のモデレーションを行なってくださった皆さんのおかげです。心よりお礼申し上げます。

[image]

記念すべき5周年をお祝いするために「公開5周年オンラインもくもく会」を令和2年2月22日（土）に開催いたします。コアメンバーとして[ento](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento)さん、[nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)さんがお手伝いくださいます。公開5周年記念プレゼントは、もくもく会の参加者全員にお送りする予定です。

5年間、知識の積み重ねをどうもありがとうございました。次は10周年に向かって、これからもスタック・オーバーフローをよろしくお願いいたします！