# 2月22日 (土) 13時〜 もくもく会を開催します → 開催しました！

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

**追記：2020年2月22日(土)にスタック・オーバーフロー祝5周年オンラインもくもく会を開催しました！**

ご参加頂いた皆さんへ：
お忙しい中お集まり頂きまして本当にありがとうございました。オンラインイベントは初めての試みでしたが、ご参加くださった皆さん一人一人のおかげで[楽しくかつ集中して作業ができる会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3262/14055)になり大変嬉しく思います。もくもく会に参加できなかった方にも、スタック・オーバーフローを5周年に導いた全ての人への「ありがとう」が伝わったのではないでしょうかヽ(´▽｀)/。そして、この会のコアメンバーの @ento さんと @nekketsuuu さんにも、改めてお礼を申し上げたいと思います。もくもく会が成功したのはお二人が中心となってプラン/リード下さったおかげです。ぜひまた[オンラインもくもく会を開催](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3263/14055)できればと思います。ユーザーの皆さんが中心となって開催できるよう今後もサポートして参りますのでどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

素晴らしい5年間、そして5周年イベントをどうもありがとうございました m(_ _)m 
今後とも引き続きスタック・オーバーフローをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします！

---

https://soja.connpass.com/event/164865/ （申込みは締切りました）

ハッシュタグ： [#SOもくもく](https://twitter.com/hashtag/SO%E3%82%82%E3%81%8F%E3%82%82%E3%81%8F)

以下、connpassに掲載した説明文からの抜粋です。

---

スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティの皆さんでオンラインもくもく会を開催します！

スタック・オーバーフローは公開から5周年を無事むかえることができました！5年間こつこつ参加くださった方も、最近投稿し始めたという方も、しばらくお休みしていた方も、一緒にゆるくもくもくしましょう！5周年をお祝いするために今回のオンラインもくもく会の参加者全員にプレゼントをお送りする予定です＼(^o^)／。

参加される方へ：**connpassとスタック・オーバーフローとで登録名が異なる場合、参加時のコメント等でスタック・オーバーフロー側の登録名を教えてください。**

#### もくもく会とは

一般的なもくもく会はITエンジニアが黙々と開発作業や独習を行う会を意味しますが、スタック・オーバーフローのオンラインもくもく会は、ユーザーが、各自、居心地の良いカフェやオフィス、自宅などからSOja交流会チャット（オンライン）に集合し、スタック・オーバーフローを利用しながら、好きなように開発や独習を黙々と進めるスタイルの勉強会です。

#### もくもく集合場所

スタック・オーバーフロー・メタ又は交流会チャット（オンライン）で集合です！

**スタック・オーバーフロー・メタ**：https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/
当日、開始のお知らせと詳しい参加案内を投稿します。

**SOja交流会部屋**：https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja
スタック・オーバーフローの信用度が20未満の方はメタのコメント欄で @aki までお知らせください m_ _m。Stack Exchangeのサイトでは通常20の信用度がチャットの発言に必要ですが、祝5周年オンラインもくもく会参加については本チャットルームの制限を解除できればと思います。

#### もくもく時間

3時間を予定していますが、途中入退室OKです。
日本在住の方はもちろん世界各国で活躍されている方も、どこからでも参加が可能です。

**おおまかな流れ**：スタック・オーバーフロー・メタにて開始のお知らせ → 今日やることをチャットにてシェア（任意）→ もくもく → 今日やったことをチャットにてシェア（任意）→ 解散

**Moku Moku Time**
**Friday, Feb 21, 2020**
20:00 - 23:00 PST (San Francisco) 
23:00 - 2:00 EST (Boston & NY) 
**Saturday, Feb 22, 2020**
4:00 - 7:00 GMT (London) 
7:00 - 10:00 MSK (St. Petersburg & Moscow) 
13:00 - 16:00 JST (Tokyo)

#### もくもくすること

このもくもく会では、スタック・オーバーフローに関することなら何でもして OK です。
まとまった時間を用意して、みんなで一人ひとり何かに取り組むことがもくもく会の目標です。
以下に題材の例を挙げてみます

- 新しく質問を投稿する。
- 質問に回答を投稿する。特に、ちょっと回答をつくるのが面倒そうなものなど。
- 質問や回答を見ながら、自分の開発を進める。投票をする。良い回答をシェアする。
- 自己回答として知見を投稿し、「蛍の光」バッジ獲得を目指す。
- 他言語の Q&A を[翻訳・校正](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2930/19110)して日本語版に輸入する。
- [たくさん投票されているものの未解決な質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)に回答を投稿する。
- コメントのみで解決している質問のうち、コメントのコードが追検証が可能なものについてサンプルコード付きでコミュニティWikiで回答する。
- 自分の回答を見直し、文章を直したり、情報を更新したりする。
- タグ wiki を充実させる。
- https://ja.traducir.win/ で翻訳を進める。
- 未解決のメタ投稿に筋道をつける。
- サイトのバグを見つけ、メタに投稿する。
- などなど

#### 参加者プレゼント

[image: SOオリジナル✨]

もくもく会の参加者全員に、SOオリジナル靴下、ウォーターボトル、Tシャツの中からお好きなものを2つお送りする予定です。（プラスα？もしかすると他にも何か嬉しいものがもらえるかもしれません（^人^)）

関連：
[サイトの未翻訳箇所を見つけて、もくもく会で直しましょう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3209/14055)
[祝🎂スタック・オーバーフロー公開5周年](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3155/14055)

Comment: なんとなく想像は付く / 既にみんな知ってるのかもしれませんが、「もくもく会」とはなんなのか簡単な説明があると親切なのかなぁと思います (僕は今回初めてこのフレーズを知りました)。

Comment: 参加します。私の想定しているタスクは「コメントのみで解決している質問のうち、コメントのコードが追検証が可能なものについてサンプルコード付きでコミュニティWikiで回答する」ことです。私はWeb系に弱いのでpythonやc#中心に参加しますが、他のギークのご尽力をいただけると(回答ゼロで)消えてほしくない質問が消えなくなる([リンク先項番10.RemoveAbandonedQuestions](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/9820))ので、貴重な日本語QA保全の視点からも価値ある活動です。ぜひどうぞ。

Comment: タスク候補: 技術系のスタッフは海外の方になるので、「バグ報告」や「機能要望」で放置されているもののうち、日本語版ローカルで発生していそうな問題については、英語が得意な人が [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) に翻訳して投稿してもらえると何かしらの進展に繋がるかもしれません。

Comment: チャットコメントにありました「もっと気軽に投票してもらうよう(今回のような)イベントをしてもよいのかも。」のように「『総選挙』バッチを取得する」などもタスクとして有効かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 14):

## もくもく会を開催しました！

2月22日、日本ではお昼時の13時から、予定通りもくもく会を開催しました。

それぞれの方がみなさんもくもくと何かに取り組む、楽しい時間となりました！

この投稿ではもくもく会の様子をお届けすると共に、みなさんがなさったことの一部をご紹介しようと思います。

### 様子

オンラインもくもく会は、コミュニティ・マネージャーである Nicolas さんの投稿からスタートしました。

[image: Nicolas「みんな、おはよう！今日ここでお会いできてうれしいです。」]

[公開5周年をお祝いしましょう！🌸](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3260/19110)

その後、挨拶したりやることを宣言したりなどし、各自作業に入りました。オンラインなので静か……。

### 途中

もくもくと言いつつ、チャットで会話も OK という形でしたので、いくつか会話や議論がありました。

[こちらにログがあります](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja)。オンラインでも数人集まると議論がどんどん進むのは面白い体験でした。

### おしまい

3 時間でみなさんどんなことをなさったのでしょうか。報告自由にしておりましたので、ご報告くださった方のものを抜粋しつつご紹介します。

payaneco さんは、コメントで解決済みとなっていた質問の回答を整える作業をしてくださいました。開始直後に https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/63248/19110 が投稿され、びっくりしたのを覚えています。

alg さんは、Traducir で大量の翻訳をしてくださいました。的確な翻訳が高速で送られてきて、僕は驚きっぱなしでした。aki さんが裏で翻訳の確認と承認を行ってくださったので、来週あたりには反映されるかと思います。

kishikawa katsumi さんは、ふたつの質問に筋道をつけてくださいました。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/63257/19110 の回答から、チャットの方で定数とメモリ上の配置について話が続きました。

akira ejiri さんは、今まで自分がした回答を改善する活動をしてくださいました。自分が最初にした回答の修正までされていて、見習いたい気分です。僕も回答の保全活動をしなければ……。

sayuri さんは、[api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) タグは不要なのでは？　という問題提起をなさってくださいました。[チャットで盛り上がり](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53612197#53612197)、いくつか発見もあったのでメタで議論を続けられればなと思います。

cubick さんは、タグの見直しやタグ wiki・タグ wiki 抜粋の編集、および翻訳作業をしてくださいました。タグが健全に充実すると質問も回答もしやすくなるので、地味ですが大事な作業と思います。

ento さんは、気軽に書ける静的型付け言語を探すため、自分用のスクリプトをひとつ Crystal で書きなおしてみてらっしゃいました。[crystal-lang](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-lang) の質問が無いことが分かったので、Crystal ユーザーの皆さんはチャンスです。

ぼく nekketsuuu は、[このご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61829/19110)に自分なりの回答をつけました。この質問が投稿されてから何回か回答を考えては消しており、今回のものももっと推敲できそうでしたが Done is better than perfect を信じて投稿しました。

また、ここには書いておりませんがもくもくとこっそり活動されていた方々もいらっしゃったようです　お疲れ様でした。

最後に、みなさま、本当にありがとうございました！　皆さまが楽しく作業できる会を開催できたこと、嬉しく思います。共同で主催をしてくださり、どのような形での開催にするか色々と議論してくださった ento さん、開催に先立ち様々な準備や声掛けをしてくださった aki さんと Nicolas さんにも改めて感謝いたします。

それでは、また次の交流会でお会いできるのを楽しみにしております。

<sub>[↓aki さん謹製 Raspberry Pi です。](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53612707#53612707)</sub>

[image: aki さん謹製ラズベリーパイ]

Answer (score 5):

チャットはあまり目立たないところにあるのもあって普段はあまり活発に利用されていない印象なのですが、もくもく会で時間を決めて人が集まることで、書こうかどうか迷っていた内容も気軽にシェアできたのは個人的に良かった点です。

今回は5周年をきっかけとして「もくもく会」を催しましたが、オンラインでやるのだから月一とかの定期的なイベントとして行ってもいいんじゃないかなと思いました。