# 公開5周年をお祝いしましょう！

Tags: 討議, 交流会

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

本当に素晴らしいことです！私たちは過去5年間にわたり、プログラミングに関する質問や回答を日本語で蓄積しながら互いに助け合ってきました！この5年間では：

- 20,000を超える質問と25,000の回答というナレッジを収集し、現在質問の78％が回答済みです。
- 約25,000人の登録ユーザーをサイトに迎えました。
- 1日あたり約14,000回の訪問がありました。

大切な事は、私たちが力を合わせればプログラミングの世界をさらに良い方向へ変えることなのではないでしょうか。今すぐに、日本語で、ここスタック・オーバーフローで！

素晴らしいパフォーマンスです。さらに前進しましょう！

#### 5年間：とても順調です！

ゼロからコミュニティを作ることは非常に難しいタスクです。コミュニティはロケットのようなもので発射させること自体が難しいのです。ナレッジベースの新しい質問や回答の一つ一つがコミュニティに力を与え、前進することができます。

サイトに参加し、そして努力を続け、私たちをこの5周年に導いた全ての人に「ありがとう」と声をかけあいましょう！仲間を助け、コミュニティに知識を提供してくださり本当にありがとうございました。5年はまだ始まったばかりだと思います。おそらく、この先にもっと興味深い質問や回答が私たちを待っていることでしょう！

#### 公開5周年パーティーを開催しましょう：もくもく会！

コミュニティの誕生を祝うには好きなことをするのが一番です。もちろん、他のユーザーと一緒に楽しみましょう！さぁ、今からもくもく会をスタートして公開5周年をお祝いましょう！

参加ルールは簡単です：

1. “SOja交流会”チャットにて「ハロー」と一言挨拶
2. 今日やることをチャットにてシェア（任意です）
3. もくもく開始！スタック・オーバーフローに関することなら何でもOK
4. 今日やったことをチャットにてシェア（こちらも任意です） (スクリーンショット、簡単なテキストや写真 などがあるとわかりやすいかもしれません）

最も素晴らしい賞品といえば知識であり、参加することにそもそも意義があるのですが、今回は嬉しい参加賞を全員にお送りします＼(^o^)／。それでは、今から開始しましょう♪

関連：
[2月22日 (土) 13時〜 もくもく会を開催します🎉](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3235/14055)
[サイトの未翻訳箇所を見つけて、もくもく会で直しましょう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3209/14055)
[祝🎂スタック・オーバーフロー公開5周年](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3155/14055)